# Adding a constraint to a Splunk search yields more result rows

Tags: nosql, splunk

Consider the following two Splunk searches:

```
index=a | join type=inner MyKey [search index=b]
```

and:

```
index=a | join type=inner MyKey [search index=b | where MyVal > 0]
```

Remarkably, the latter of the searches - the search whose subsearch has a constraint - has *three times as many* result rows as the former.

The [Splunk documentation page](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Join) for the `join` command suggests semantics that are close enough for the sake of argument to SQL's `join`:

> A join is used to combine the results of a search and subsearch if specified fields are common to each. You can also join a table to itself using the selfjoin command.

This snippet is relevant to the `type=inner` argument:

> A join is used to combine the results of a search and subsearch if specified fields are common to each. You can also join a table to itself using the selfjoin command.

Based on this information, I assume the two Splunk searches above should be equivalent to the following SQL, respectively:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.MyKey = b.MyKey
```

and:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.MyKey = b.MyKey
WHERE b.MyVal > 0
```

How is it possible that adding a constraint increases the number of result rows?

Interestingly, the following Splunk search produces a *third* result - one that matches what I got when I put the same data in an SQL database:

```
index=a | join type=outer MyKey [search index=b | eval hasmatch=1]
| where hasmatch=1
```

Some more notes:

- the `MyVal` field has no duplicates in either table / index
- I have verified that the raw events in Splunk's indexes match the raw source data in event counts and values for `MyVal`
- the only search-time operations configured for the relevant sourcetypes in `props.conf` is a `report` to extract the fields based on a stanza in `transforms.conf` (the source data is in a CSV dialect)

Can anyone give me some clues here? As far as I'm concerned this behaviour is nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you re-post this question over at the official Splunk forums (splunk-base.splunk.com). There are some very useful and experience "Splunkers" there (Employees, customers, partners, etc.) and it may be a better place for your question.

Cheers,

MHibbin

Comment: I have posted the question there too:

http://splunk-base.splunk.com/answers/61942/adding-a-constraint-to-a-subsearch-yields-more-result-rows

Unfortunately no responses thus far.